# Being even or odd in the product expansion $\prod(1+x^k+x^{k+1})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, asymptotics

Consider the generating function of "partitions with distinct parts"
$$\sum_nQ(n)x^n=\prod_k(1+x^k).$$
It's known that
$$\left[\prod_k(1+x^k)\right] \mod 2=\prod_m(1-x^m)=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}x^{j(3j-1)/2}.$$
So, $Q(n)$ is "more often" even than odd.

Define the product
$$\prod_{k\geq1}(1+x^k+x^{k+1})=\sum_nU(n)x^n$$
and the proportionals
$$\eta(N)=\frac{\#\{0\leq n\leq N: \text{$U(n)$ is odd}\}}N.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that $\eta(N)\geq\frac12$, for large $N$? Experiments seem to suggest so.

Comment: for the record, this is https://oeis.org/A160571

Comment: I've computed $U(n)$ mod $2$ up to $n=100000$ and it doesn't seem true. We have $\eta(N)\ge \frac{1}{2}$ up to roughly $N=4000$  but at this point  $\eta(N)$ goes below $\frac{1}{2}$ and stays there for a while. $\eta(N)$ crosses $\frac{1}{2}$ again around $N=99500$. The behavior of $\eta(N)$ seem overall somewhat chaotic and I think that it might well cross $\frac{1}{2}$ infinitely often.