# Partity of partitions with distinct parts of parts $>1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

This question is motivated by [my earlier (unanswered) MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390446/being-even-or-odd-in-the-product-expansion-prod1xkxk1).

The *number of partitions into distinct parts* is generated by $\sum_{n\geq0}Q(n)x^n=\prod_{k\geq1}(1+x^k)$. Focusing on parity of coefficients $Q(n) \,\,\text{mod}\,\, 2$, the series takes the form $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}x^{j(3j-1)/2}$.

In light of these matters, consider the modified product $\prod_{k\geq2}(1+x^k)$. It might be easy but I still like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$\prod_{k\geq2}(1+x^k) \mod 2=1+(x^2+x^3+x^4)+(x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}+x^{11})+\cdots$$
> to say that consecutive terms appear with block-lengths: $1, 3, 5, 7, 9,\dots$; that is, odd numbers.

**NOTE.** $\prod_{k\geq2}(1+x^k)$ generates partitions into distinct parts with parts larger than $1$.

Comment: just multiply the right hand side of your hypothetical relation by $1+x$ and verify that you get $\sum x^{j(3j-1)/2}$

Comment: @FedorPetrov that's the thought, but let's have the details verified. I don't expect this problem to be difficult but more discussion may come out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\prod_{k\geq 2} (1+x^k) = \frac{\prod_{k\geq 1} (1+x^k)}{1+x} \equiv \sum_{j\geq 0} \frac{x^{j(3j+1)/2} + x^{(j+1)(3j+2)/2}}{1+x}$$
$$\equiv \sum_{j\geq 0} x^{j(3j+1)/2}\frac{1 - x^{2j+1}}{1-x}\equiv \sum_{j\geq 0} x^{j(3j+1)/2}(1+x+\dots+x^{2j}) \pmod{2}.$$